# SQL- How to get two different column's values inside one column and two results?

Tags: mysql, sql, request, mariadb

This title might be weird but I'm looking for a query which can do this:

I have 1 line which looks like this in my table:

Sensor_address | type_measure_1 | type_measure_2

I would like to do a SQL query which can give me something like this:

> - result 1 : Sensor_address = X | type_measure = type_measure_1
> - result 2 : Sensor_address = X (the same) | type_measure = type_measure_2

Is this possible in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT Sensor_address, type_measure_1 as type_measure FROM [table] 
UNION ALL
SELECT Sensor_address, type_measure_2 as type_measure FROM [table]
```

Comment: It works perfectly ! I just added a "where" condition. Thank you !